# Eclipse Photon with JPA: import javax.persistence can not be resolved

Tags: eclipse, jpa-2.1, jpa-2.2

I installed `GlassFish 5` and `GlassFish Tools` (from http://download.eclipse.org/glassfish-tools/1.0.0/repository/). I also tried with GlassFish 4.1.1, results were the same.

I created a new JPA Project (**JPA 2.1**):

[image]

In Data Source Explorer View of Eclipse, I added and tested a Database Connection:

- Connection Profile: Derby
- "Derby Embedded JDBC Driver 10.2" with driver file `~/glassfish5/javadb/lib/derby.jar`

Next, I added an entity file `MD.java`. The boilerplate code gives me an error:

```
The import javax.persistence can not be resolved.
```

[image]

I wanted to get rid of this error, but "Search repositories for javax.persistence" does not yield any search result.

**First question**: How to fix this in Eclipse? If it was a Maven Project (not JPA project), I think I would have added to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Second question**: In "Project Facets" of project properties (and upon creation of "JPA Project"), I am able to select only JPA versions less or equal `2.1`. How can I use `JPA 2.2` in an Eclipse JPA Project?

As you might have guessed by now, I am quite new to Eclipse...

Comment: Which release of Eclipse is this?

Comment: Version: Photon Release (4.8.0)
Build id: 20180619-1200

Comment: It would seem that it was not updated to allow for JPA 2.2. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=522302